# iOS 9 Swift UIButton CheckBox subclass not showing image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ios9, subclass

I subclassed `UIButton` to make a `CheckBox`... The code below seems to work on storyboard (according to online tutorials) but when i try to add it by code it doesn't work...

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {

    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "Checked.png")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "Unchecked.png")! as UIImage

    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            isChecked = !isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use on my `ViewController` to add the CheckBox:

```
let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 40, height: 40))
print(checkbox.isChecked)
view.addSubview(checkbox)
```

The problem is that the `CheckBox` is not being displayed. If I give it a background, under the frame initialization then I can see the square but if nothing happens when I click it.. Even after adding a print message in the `buttonClicked` method.

I added print statements in the awakeFromNib method and it was never called...

Comment: can you call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they require? Although the default implementation of this method does nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may call the super implementation at any point during your own awakeFromNib method.

Comment: Are you setting on and of in cellForRowAtIndexPath? As tableview is resuing cells you need to update button everytim

Comment: @KuntalGajjar no table is being used anywhere in the code.

Comment: @idindu calling super.awakeFromNib() at the top of the awakeFromNib override doesn't change anything.

Comment: @crubio any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.. 
AwakeFromNib apparently never gets called without Storyboard so I had to implement a convenience initializer.